# MobileFirst 6.3 issues connecting adapter to https webservice

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to connect my adapter to an https web service however whenever I invoke it I get the following error:

```
Http request failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Do I need to do anything special to connect to https webservice? I tried connecting to the same webservice using Postman and it worked fine.

Comment: Did you do anything special in postman, like first sending an authorization token and alike?

Comment: I did nothing special, I just sent a direct request to the webservice and got response.

Comment: Anything in the server logs? This single line is problematic to debug...

Comment: The console only has this error over and over alongside with:
FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure.

Is there a different server log I can check?

Comment: Do I always need to follow this:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html
Or is this only when the webservice certificate is not signed?

Comment: Yes I believe you may need to follow it. Worklight does not support unsigned. But you should look at the 6.3 docs, not 6.2...

Comment: Server logs will help to understand what exactly happens there. One of the cases when postman can reach the backend and the adapter cannot is the browser where postman is running already has imported backend certificate and the adapter doesn't trust to backend cert.

Comment: Hi @PavelLeonov how can I check the server logs? 
I added the back-end certificate to the keystore but that didn't work, not sure what else I can do.

Comment: You can find the server log at your Eclipse workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig/worklight/logs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent two days trying suggested solutions with no luck, the server log didn't have anything other than SocketException: Connection Reset all over the place.

I solved this by creating a Java class that calls the webserivce and then called the Java class from my Adapter, I followed this tutorial to do that:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/adding_a_java_based_worklight_adapter_to_your_mobile_application7?lang=en